# Windows Printing Via Python

Tags: python, printing

I trying to print ".txt" file via python . I do print the file but how I can to get print menu to select the printer and all properties or printing .
i use this code to print , it print on default printer and will not open the print menu ?

```
win32api.ShellExecute (0,"print",filename,None,".",0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is possibly to open `notepad.exe` with that file and let  user select 'Print' from there. It would also serve as a preview window.

Comment: you mean there is no way to open print menu by Python ??

Comment: There is, but last time I checked it was a bit complicated since you had to control many other aspects of printing, like the actual sending data to a printer driver. The quick and easy way is to delegate this hassle to a program that someone has already written. BTW, doing the same thing with MSO or OOo to generate fancily formatted reports saves lots of effort.